# How to copy a hyperlink from a single cell in excel to a word document which is being created and populated by VBA aleady?

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, ms-word

Very inexperienced with VBA, but trying to work on a project.  I have an excel file with lots of contact information.  Each entry contains Names, phone numbers, addresses for a particular family.

I am creating an address book of sorts with this information, which requires a Word document (yes, there would be other ways to do this, but it's a joint project, and this is the chosen method).

I am able to populate the entire address book in the way I want to, including page and page formatting, etc.

Obviously, most of this is a case of following through the workbook in an orderly fashion, and using TypeText to put the various pieces of information where I want them.

However, I would also like to make this a pdf, and put it on my phone, and make the phone numbers hyperlinks, so that I can dial them directly.  My only snag is maintaining the hyperlink in the transfer from Excel to Word.  It seems that .TypeText only carries the text, not the hyperlink formatting, so it's not doing what I need.

Is there something else I can do?

I am thinking that there is a Copy/Paste arrangement which would help me, but I lack enough experience to be able to insert such a routine in the middle of my code.

This is the piece of code which transfers the phone numbers over:

For y3 = (b + 1) To d

```
        'FirstPhone
        .TypeText Value(Cells(y3, 7)) & vbTab
        'LastName
        .BoldRun
        If Cells(y3, 20) = "U" Then .Font.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
        .TypeText (Cells(y3, 3))
        .Font.Underline = wdUnderlineNone
        .BoldRun
        'Logic to determine if there needs to be a hard return, and if there are more phones
        ' Add if there is a spouse, or children, etc
        .TypeText (", " & Cells(y3, 4))
          If Cells(y3, 5).Value <> "" Then .TypeText (" & " & Cells(y3, 5))
          If Cells(y3, 6) <> "" Then .TypeText ("; " & Cells(y3, 6))
            Names = Cells(y3, 3) & ", " & Cells(y3, 4) & " & " & Cells(y3, 5) & "; " & Cells(y3, 6)
            Address = Cells(y3, 15) & ", " & Cells(y3, 17) & ", " & Cells(y3, 18) & "  " & Cells(y3, 19)
          If Len(Names) + Len(Address) > 70 Or Cells(y3, 8) <> "" Then .TypeText (Chr(11))
          If Cells(y3, 8) = "" And Address = ", ,   " Then .TypeText (Chr(11))
          If Cells(y3, 8) <> "" Then .TypeText (Cells(y3, 8))
          If Cells(y3, 15) <> "" Then .TypeText (vbTab & Address)
          If Cells(y3, 8) <> "" Or Cells(y3, 15) <> "" Then .TypeText (Chr(11))
          If Cells(y3, 9) <> "" Then .TypeText (Cells(y3, 9) & Chr(11))
          If Cells(y3, 10) <> "" Then .TypeText (Cells(y3, 10) & Chr(11))
          If Cells(y3, 11) <> "" Then .TypeText (Cells(y3, 11) & Chr(11))

        Next y3
```

y3 is the index of the rows. The 7th column in the Workbook is where the phone number is located.  The rest of this section is devoted to bringing in addresses, etc... And is not so necessary for the question.

Prior to this piece of code, I have already created the Word Doc, chosen some formatting, and printed a section heading in the Word Doc.  That's why I can begin here by simply TypeText the contents of the cell in question.

What I would like to know is:  How can I copy a hyperlink of a telephone number here, rather than simply typing the text into the WordDoc?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do what you describe, it would be useful to make the transition from user emulation (the macro, likely recorded, does exactly what a user does) to working with Word's object model. Since only a code snippet is provided, it's difficult to demonstrate what this means, but...

Rather than `Selection.TypeText`, in this context, it means working with a `Range` object, to which text can be assigned (`Range.Text = "abc"`). The `Range`can then also be used as the target object for creating a `Hyperlink` object.

Taking just the line of code that seems to deal with the telephone number:

```
Dim rng as Word.Range `or Object, if late-binding is use - not evident from the code in the question
Set rng = Selection.Range
If Cells(y3, 11) <> "" Then 
    rng.Text = Cells(y3, 11) & Chr(11)  'Assign normal text
    'rng.Parent is the document. I use this since there's no information in 
    'the question about how the document is manipulated in this code
    rng.Parent.Hyperlinks.Add rng, "link information"
End If
```

Note that I cannot give you the hyperlink address information as I do not know what that might be for a telephone number. My system does not hyperlink to telephone numbers. You have to research what the valid hyperlink address would be for a telephone number. Best would probably be to create one directly in Word, then press Alt+F9 to toggle to the underlying field code. That basic format is what is needed for `"link information"` in the code snippet, above.

Comment: Thank you Cindy.  I am using early-binding, so that will answer that for you.  The piece in question is actually (y3,7) the phone number in question, and it is at the beginning of the piece of code I have quoted.  (y3,8) and (y3,9), (y3,10) and (y3,11) are also phone numbers, and you can see that all I am doing with them (at least the last ones) is inserting them at the left margin and then putting a hard return.  I have no problems creating the hyperlink.  I am not sure what you mean by "How the document is manipulated"  I would be quite happy to provide more code to be helpful in that.

Comment: And, a couple of further questions...The hyperlink already exists in Excel.  Does that make a difference? This seems to suggest it's easier to create it in the VBA process.  Secondly, the address for a phone number is: "+tel:"followed by the phone number.  And, i am not sure to do that syntactally here.  Thanks.

Comment: @RichardRaschke The key to all of this is to find out what field code syntax Word uses to hyperlink a telephone number. Look at the end of the Answer. This is not something I can do for you...

Comment: Let's say you have a phone number like 555-123-4567. What would you expect the *link text* for that phone number to be? The reality is that some systems *wrongly interpret* numbers as phone numbers, for example.

Comment: Ok.. I am trying this.....  I simply inserted Cindy's suggestion in my code:

Comment: @RichardRaschke I can't see where you've tried creating a field code to get the necessary hyperlink address, as described *a the end of my answer* - after the code.

Comment: Thanks again.  I have now put in this:                                                                
            Dim rng As Word.Range
            Set rng = Selection.Range
            For y3 = (b + 1) To d
            
            'FirstPhone
            '.TypeText (Cells(y3, 7)) & vbTab
            
            If Cells(y3, 7) <> "" Then
                rng.Text = Cells(y3, 7)
                rng.Parent.Hyperlinks.Add rng, ("tel:320-648-8777" \ t)
            End If......................Again, the code seems to hang on the step of "Set rng = Selection.Range

Comment: @RichardRaschke You don't provide enough code context. You "obviously" have a `With` in the code, somewhere "above" the code shown in the question. Without knowing exactly what that is, one can only guess. You might *try* `Set rng = .Range`. FWIW I doubt very much that `Hyperlinks.Add` in your comment will work as `\t` is "nonsense"...

Comment: Thank you Cindy.  As I say, I am a very big rookie at this.  Now, I have a section of code reading like this: As you say, inside of With....the code reads...            
            'Print Individual information
        
            Dim rng As Word.Range
            Set rng = .Range
            For y3 = (b + 1) To d
            
            'FirstPhone
                rng.Text = Cells(y3, 7) & Chr(11)
                PhoneString = "+tel:" & Cells(y3, 7)
                rng.Parent.Hyperlinks.Add rng, PhoneString..And, this works, but see next comment

Comment: The problem now is that I get the hyperlink, and it is correct, but it is printed after the next section of code (if you look at the original, that's a last name and potentially an address, and there is a 9604 error code.  I don't really understand how the next part of the code can be executed and .TypeText go in there BEFORE the hyperlink for the phone number.  Thank you again.  This is very helpful, and I am sorry for not copying the entire code in the first place.

Comment: Please forgive me.  That is a 6028 error code.  My mistake.

Comment: What's the error *message*? No one memorizes the numbers... And it would help for you to use the [edit] link below your question to update it with the *current* code that is inserting the Hyperlink but in the wrong place. Indicate the line of code causing the error (important!) and show screen shots of what the result looks like as well as how the result *should* look.

Comment: Thanks again Cindy.  The error was due to the Set command not being within the print loop.  And, I had to learn how to use Selection.direction to move the insertion point to the end of the hyperlink rather than the beginning.  All is well now. Thank you so much.